# Often can't kill window in Sway

Tags: sway

One problem I have using Sway is zombie apps that get hung and cannot be killed from within Sway.

Sway has a "kill" command which by default is bound to the hotkey mod+Shift+Q, however this command is a soft kind of kill that apparently just nicely asks the process to quit. So, if the process is hung, then it just ignores the command and the window stays open. In this situation what I have to do is switch to a terminal and kill the offending application from the command line which seems kind of ridiculous to me that I have to do this.

Is there some functionality in Sway that I am missing that allows me to kill a window with a hung process in it?